# Opening output of last command in Vim

Tags: linux, bash, vim

It happens a lot (many times a day) when I use the `find` command, and then want to use `vim` on the path that was output from `find`.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?

`find /my/path/to/ | grep Makefile`

output: `/my/path/to/Makefile`

Then enter the cmd:  `vim /my/path/to/Makefile`

Comment: `vim $(!!)` might be efficient. Or you could use the mouse to just copy and paste it.

Comment: @FDinoff `!! | xargs vim`, but wont work with weird filenames.

Comment: I like `vim $(!!)`.  Better than using the mouse!

Comment: @AndyJ0076 That works for file(s) without spaces.  Different use-cases, different folks.

Comment: I found if there's multiple results from the `find` command, you can use `vim $(!!) -o` to open each one in a split window.  Cool!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply `cd` to your project and start Vim:

```
$ cd /my/path/to/ && vim
```

and tell it to open all the files that satisfy your requirements:

```
:args **/Makefile
```

If you really insist

Answer (score 0):

```
vim `find /my/path/to/ | grep Makefile`
```

Comment: Potentially unsafe use of file names.

Answer (score -1):

#### Opening one file at a time

This will work even with path/file names that include spaces, tabs, or whatever:

```
find /my/path/to/ -name 'MakeFile'  -exec vim {} \;
```

If more than one MakeFile is found, each will be opened in `vim` in turn.

The above assumes that you wanted to edit was called `MakeFile`.  As a less restrictive version, this will find and edit a file that has the characters MakeFile anywhere in its name:

```
find /my/path/to/ -name '*MakeFile*'  -exec vim {} \;
```

#### Opening all files in one `vim` session

```
find /my/path/to/ -name 'MakeFile' -exec vim {} +
```

When opening multiple files like this, `vim` will start with the first named file.  To get to the next file, use `:n`.  To get to the third, use `:n` again.  To get back to the first, use `:rewind`.

Comment: If there happen to be multiple Makefiles, this will spawn n vim processes instead of 1.

Comment: @Barry I tried it before I posted this.  On my system, it spawns one at a time, just like the answer stated.  Did it work differently on your system?

Comment: It's much nicer to have a single vim session than n and have to worry about Ctrl-C or Ctrl-/ at just the right moment.

Comment: @Barry Again, it didn't work that way for me. It opens one vim session at a time.  Only when one one vim session exits does the next one open.  If you tried it and works differently for you, please provide precise details.

Comment: I know how find works, thanks.  To clarify, `:n` (next file) and `:N` (previous file) will not work across vim processes.  The last answer that was just added is more-less equivalent to `xargs`.

Comment: @Barry I added a solution that, for those who prefer it, puts all files in one vim session.  You still have not explained why you think Ctrl-C is needed or why anything in any part of this would time sensitive.

Comment: Editing potentially many files with sequential editor processes doesn't scale.  It's unlikely on any reasonably fast box that the fork/exec process (e.g., `find`) will have the terminal long enough to be able to kill it by any of us mere mortals.  It's a whole lot easier to `:q!` than hunt for the pid of `find` to kill, Ctrl-C or Ctrl-/ hammer or close the terminal.

Answer (score -3):

Gettext (and others) has a lot of crazy shortcuts. Some of them are highly useful. Jumping "home" (ctrl+a) and to "end" (crtl+e) is one of them.

To acheive what you describe, you can use the good old sell command expansion.

## 1. find -name whatever

/found/someting/overe/here/whatever

### 2. <kbd>up</kbd>

### 3. <kbd>`</kbd>

### 4. <kbd>Ctrl +</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>

### 5. <kbd>vim</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>

### 6. <kbd>return</kbd>

## alternative:

### 1. <kbd>vim `find -name foo`</kbd>

### 2. <kbd>Ctrl +</kbd> <kbd>Alt +</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd>

Comment: To me, learning some essential shortcuts and using them to "automate" usual tasks is effective enough. I don't think this deserves a down-vote.